# Session variable passed dynamically to the next page

Tags: php, html, session-variables

This code here is working perfectly well. All i want to do is to pass the FirstName  and LastName (using SESSION) which is already stored in the $userName. The first and last name is actually retrieved from the database when trying to login.
I want to have the First and Last Name show on every page once logged in.. Thanks

```
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td><?php
 $DisplayForm = TRUE;
 $errors = 0;

if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
include("dbconnect.php");
if($DBConnect !== FALSE){
$SQLstring = "SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE username ='".
$_POST['uname']. "' and password = '".md5($_POST['pass'])."'";
$DisplayForm = FALSE;
$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $DBConnect);
echo mysql_error();
if (mysql_num_rows($QueryResult)=== 0){
  echo "<p style='color:red;'><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The email address/password " . 
  " combination is not valid.</b></p>\n";
  ++$errors;
  $DisplayForm = TRUE;
}
else
{
  $DisplayForm = FALSE;
}

 }

 } 

if ($DisplayForm)
{?>


<form id="form1" name="loginForm" method="post" action="index.php">
 <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="93" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username:</strong></td>
  <td width="149" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input type="text" name="uname" id="textfield" /></td>
  <td width="76" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong>Password:</strong></td>
  <td width="150" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><label for="textfield2"></label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></td>
  <td width="196" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><input type="image" name="login" src="images/login.jpg" />&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="68" bgcolor="#DACFAF">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="68" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong><a href="register.php">Register</a>   </strong>   </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
  </form>

 <?php }
  else {
    $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
  $userID = $Row['userid'];
  $userName = $Row['first_name']. " ". $Row['last_name'];


  echo "<table width=780px border=0px >";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td style='color:red;'>";
              echo "<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome back, $userName!</b>";
              echo "</td>";
              echo"<td align='right'>";
              echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
              echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='logout'>";
              echo "</form>";
              echo "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</table>";


  }


 ?>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: _What is your problem exactly ?_

Comment: what result you getting now?

Comment: Am not sure how to really pass the session. i can pass between forms but the dynamic is not really working.

Comment: I want to have the First and Last Name show on every page once logged in.. --> to answer this: Why not just print your session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to set $_SESSION variable.

or if not

In your log in php start a session using `session_start();`. after all the checking is done. Put the name inside of the `$_SESSION` variable.

like this

`$_SESSION['username'] = $firstname.$lastname;`

assuming $firstname has the user's first name and $lastname has the user's last name.

THEN:

Put `session_start();` at the very beginning of your PHP file that you want to display the username.

then

`$userName=$_SESSION['username'];`

Put this two together at the very start of every php file you want to display the name.
Now you can use the variable `$userName` to display the name.

Comment: Thanks. i was able to fix it by adding  $_SESSION['username'] = "$userName";   The issue i had before was that i was adding it to the session declared at the top of the page